# How do I send textarea data to another page?

Tags: html, post

I am new to this kind of things... I need to submit the data in 3 text areas to another page...
How do I do that?
P.S. I would have used inputs, if I could.

Comment: are you familiar with any server side scripting?

Comment: well.... <form action="someOtherPage"> <textarea ...>...</textarea><button type="submit">...</button></form>??

Comment: PHP, that's what I am going to use to get the results and put them in the database. I also use it to retrieve some data and put in that text areas. @yankee, from W3 specs, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create your page with form... For example call it form.html
use this code for example:

```
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="acceptpage.php">
  <input type="text" name="input" id="textfield" />
  <textarea name="text" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send" />
  </form>
```

After that create page called acceptpage.php
Put this in between body tags

```
<?php
$frominput = $_POST[input]; // Variable who accept your data from input
$fromtextarea = $_POST[text]; // Variable who accept your data from textarea
// You don't need to use variables, but if you starter, easier to understand.
    // Do something with your arrived data... 
// Stupid, but for short explanation... for example echo it...
echo $fromtextarea;
echo $frominput;
?>
```

Of course, you can send data with html, but you can't accept data, for accepting data you need a programming language like php. I use php above to show you how it works...

Edit...(I just now saw that you want to you put the data into the database)...
Here is code:

```
<?php
$frominput = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[input]);
$fromtextarea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[text]);
// Do something with your arrived data... 
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (rowforinput, rowfortextarea) VALUES
    ('$frominput','$fromtextarea')") or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

As you can see, there are little modifications at variables which accept data, I called mysql_real_escape_string function, to make data more secure. If you want to learn more about mysql_real_escape_string function, [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Don't forget that first you make a connection to the database. For it I usually make my own function:

```
        function connect_db() {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
        mysql_select_db("database");
                      }
```

And call function with `<?php connect_db(); ?>`

**UPDATE 03.15.2015**

A lot of changes since 2011 in PHP. Function `mysql_connect` will be deprecated in future. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Reference:

[mysql_connect deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

[MySQL Improved Extension (Mysqli)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[PHP Data Objects Interface (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: M'kay. I am going to try this out.

Comment: When you send data with form, for first you are interested in `name="somethnig"`, also make different id's, call them as you want. For more complex things, it will be important.

Comment: See also my edit please, for inserting data in database. It`s important because mysql_real_escape_string ... Best wishes

Comment: Thanks but I already knew PHP and the function to escape large text, because they might interfere with SQL markup and all that... I just didn't know that text areas can be send with POST. :)